# Axios post request to ngrok server - why am I not receiving any data in req.body?

Tags: node.js, axios, localhost, ngrok

Im making an axios post request to my server. client is run on localhost. To make this happen, I am using ngrok. I resolved the CORS errors by adding specific headers to my axios request. However, I am not seeing any data on req.body. I was looking at all similar posts and just dont understand why i am not sending any data. Any help would be really appreciated!!!

axios request:

```
...
const posting = async () => {
      await axios.post('http://a410-xxx-c455-d1e8-1c8a-fa19.ngrok-free.app/someRequest',
            { title: 'world' }, {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }}
        );
    ...
}
```

index.js

```
const app = require ('./app');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

app.js

```
routes(app);
```

routes.js

```
 app.use(router.post('/someRequest', (req, res, next) => {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log(req.body)
 }))
```

Comment: Your CORS issue is a separate problem. You should [as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it and not try to move the goalposts on this one. (And you should include a [mcve]. Showing the code you use to load the `cors` module with no context for how it fits into the rest of your server code can hide the problem.)

Comment: Well I added the few lines regarding cors. Not sure if thats more clear now. I also do not know how to make a reproducible example with localhost!!

Answer (score 0):

You **claim** to be sending Form URL Encoded data.

> ```
> "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> ```

---

However you are passing an object to Axios so it will JSON encode the data.

> ```
>  { title: 'world' }
> ```

---

And the only body parsing middleware you have only supports JSON encoded data

> ```
>  app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

---

You need:

- A body parser
- A data format
- A content type header

… which **all match**.

Since you claim to be sending URL Encoded data, the JSON parser doesn't trigger.

Axios would set the correct Content-Type header automatically if you didn't override it.

**Omit** the `headers` property.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I remove the headers in my axios request, I get the CORS error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://a410-2003xxxa19.ngrok-free.app/someRequest' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Comment: @learncode — So **properly** enable support for CORS on your API. It's well documented and the cors module on npm makes it easy. Reinventing the wheel by sticking `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` isn't enough because it can't handle preflights.

Comment: I have tried so many things on my server. I also used cors module, it still gives me the cors error, unless I add headers to my axios request

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about how to use the `cors` module properly then.

Comment: Im not sure what to ask as I think Im using it just like documented. I add the cors middleware to my single route. I also tried as suggested in the documentation to add options.

Comment: You should ask a clear question, with a [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal), along with the code which generates the request, and the error message you get. You should test the code to make sure it reproduces the problem. You should reference the parts of the documentation you think are relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Its just a temporary solution but in case it helps anyone: I still couldnt solve it on the server side, so Im adding now a header in my axios request

```
 const headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
 };
```

AND on server side, I add to my route

```
 bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'})
```

like this:

```
app.use(router.post('/someRequest', bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'}), (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body)
}))
```

and now im getting the data and no cors error.